# How can I find all if-statements without an else?

Tags: find, code, find-in-files

I've got quite a lot of code in which sometimes if-statements have been written, without a matching else-statement. In some places, this is an issue, because when something fails, the failure is not handled correctly. I want to manually confirm all places an if-without-an-else occurs.

I've tried using regex, but I haven't succeeded in finding a way to match the right bracket, since regex [cannot really handle nested brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses).

The code I want to find looks like this:

```
if( ... ) {

...

}
```

The code I don't want to find, looks like this:

```
if( ... ) {

...

} 
else {

... 

}
```

How can I list all these places, so I can go through them?

Comment: I've asked the same question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68254358/how-can-i-find-all-if-statements-without-an-else
But I'm not sure where the right place to ask this is, as it is very general.

Comment: Which specific language is this? The "actually correct" answer would usually involve using a parser designed specifically for the language (e.g. in Python maybe `ast.parse()`, on in C the Coccinelle `spatch` program).

Comment: The codebase is written in several languages, but all those languages use formatting like described in the question; an IF-statement, followed by curly brackets, followed (or not) by an ELSE-statement.

Comment: What about results without an `else`, which don't require an `else`?

Comment: Whether or not they require it, is exactly what I want to confirm (manually).